# Windows Scheduler fails with error 2147942402

Tags: windows, task-scheduler

A search about the error message implies that it is due to missing resources, but the file I am trying to execute exists at the correct location.

I am currently running it with an Admin account.

If I go to the path in question, it can be executed successfully from there.

Some potential issues I can see are these;

1. The application is on a Network share, but the action is "Start a Program". Details are T:\...Path to exe which looks fine to me.
2. When I start the application manually I get a popup saying that the application comes from an "Untrusted Source".

Can someone verify that I can run an application from a Network source, using the above format?
And how do I get around the warning about the Untrusted source? It is an application I wrote, so I trust it, but that means nothing to the actual server.

Comment: If you right-click on the executable and select Properties, does it display "This file came from another computer and might be blocked"?

Comment: No Im afraid not

Comment: What type of application? Java, .NET?

Comment: Its one written in .net that I have inherited.

Comment: Are you running the task under a different user account?